# CSS files and pictures dosen't show on localhost

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

I made a website, I threw it on hosting and I have a problem. Well, on the hosting, photos and .css files work normally and load normally, but not on localhost.

I noticed that the problem is the path to which he gives to photos or .css files

For example that looks for some image:

```
<img data-src="{{ base_url() }}/public/images/background-pattern4.png" class="background-pattern-4" uk-img>
```

And this way works on hosting, but it does not work on localhost. However, when I remove 'public' from the path, it works the other way around. At localhost works and not on hosting.

I have 2 .htaccess files, first on root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

And second.. in public folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

What can I change to make the tracks work in both sides?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Laravel framework? the syntax looks like a blade template syntax. If yes then you might want to use the asset helper function like so:

```
<img data-src="{{ asset('images/background-pattern4.png') }}" class="background-pattern-4" uk-img>
```

Here's the documentation  [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset)

Comment: Nope, i'm using Slim 3 with twig